# Стили к собственному виджету - C++ Qt

Tags: c++

Всем привет! 
Столкнулся с такой трудностью:

Написал свой виджет, переопределил в нем метод paintEvent():

```
class My_PushButton : public QPushButton
{
//какой то код
};
```

Хочу к этому виджету применить стили прописанные в файле style.qss

И вот ни в какую не получается. Не применяются стили к виджету, только к собственному, ко всем остальным применяются.

через setObjectName задал имя, и в стилях пробовал по разному прописывать:

```
#mybutton
My_PushButton#mybutton
QPushButton#mybutton
QPushButton>My_PushButton#mybutton
QPushButton My_PushButton#mybutton
```

Ни один из вышеприведенных вариантов не сработал. Подскажите как правильно устанавливать селекторы, к собственным виджетам

Comment: >>переопределил в нем метод paintEvent():<< Делаете ли вы вызов родительского метода QPushButton::paintEvent внутри своего?

Comment: Сам метод не вызываю. Использую макрос Q_UNUSED(event)

Comment: Первой строчкой вашего переопределённого метода должна быть строчка вызова родительского QPushButton::paintEvent(event);

Comment: Нужно смотреть исходники QPushButton, возможно, удастся узнать от туда как он стили применяет

Comment: test123, вызов метода родительского класса решил проблему! Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Вольный перевод [официальной документации](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/stylesheet-syntax.html#widgets-inside-c-namespaces):

> Таблицы стилей Qt Style Sheets используют метод `QObject::className()`
>   для определения типа селектора. Для виджета внутри пространства имён этот
>   метод возвращает значение `<namespace>::<classname>`, которое
>   конфликтует с принятым синтаксисом Sub-Controls. Для решения этой
>   проблемы необходимо заменить `::` на `--`.

Пример:

```
namespace ns
{

class MyButton : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyButton(QWidget* parent = nullptr) :
        QPushButton(parent)
    {
        qDebug() << tr("constructor ns::MyButton() done.");
    }

};

const QString mybuttonStyle()
{
    return QString("ns--MyButton { background-color: yellow; color: red }");
}

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    ns::MyButton b;
    QObject::connect(&b, &ns::MyButton::clicked,
                     &a, &QApplication::quit);
    b.setText(a.tr("MyButton"));
    b.setStyleSheet(ns::mybuttonStyle());
    b.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Строка стиля для того же элемента, определённого без использования пространства имён, будет выглядеть так:

```
"MyButton { background-color: yellow; color: red }"
```